# What is 1f6 in Julia?

Tags: syntax, julia

In a Julia codebase I have inherited, at one point there is a division by `1f6`

So far as I can tell, this division doesn't change the output online, and I haven't been able to figure out the meaning of this step by googling "1f6 Julia."

What does it mean?

Comment: You can just type it into the REPL and see what you get It's the same as `1e6`, except in single precision, that is `Float32`.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, DNF's comment should just be the answer:

```
julia> 1f6
1.0f6

julia> typeof(1f6)
Float32

julia> Float64(1f6)
1.0e6

julia> Int(1f6)
1000000
```